# Trimming TikZ grid

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, grids

I have the following picture:

[image]

obtained from:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[invmidarrow=0.5]
(0,0) to[out=110,in=250] (0,2)
(0,2) to[out=70,in=190] (1,4)
(1,4) to[out=10,in=170] (3,4)
(3,4) to[out=-10,in=180] (4,4)
(4,4) to[out=0.in=45] (4,3)
(4,3) to[out=225,in=135] (4,2)
(4,2) to[out=-45,in=190] (4,1)
(4,1) to[out=-10,in=-10] (3,0)
(3,0) to[out=190,in=290] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

with the following key definition:

```
\tikzset{invmidarrow/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark={at position #1 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}}}}}
```

and using the `decorations.markings` library. I would like to know if there are easy ways to:

1. Trim and extend the grid so that it only fills the curve;
2. Add arrows to the grid so that all (or some of) the squares have counterclockwise arrows;
3. Add arrow tips every x*(curve length) to the curve, x being a fraction I can choose.

The picture is in Physics notes, where the teacher derived conservativity of the electric field from the nullity of its curl, and is illustrating the process by which we do so, turning the line integral into a sum of line integrals which are then turned into surface integrals of the curl over the single squares, which are imagined to become smaller and smaller.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{invmidarrow/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark={at position #1 with {\arrow{latex reversed}}}}}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) grid (4,4);
\draw[invmidarrow=0.5]
(0,0) to[out=110,in=250] (0,2)
(0,2) to[out=70,in=190] (1,4)
(1,4) to[out=10,in=170] (3,4)
(3,4) to[out=-10,in=180] (4,4)
(4,4) to[out=0.in=45] (4,3)
(4,3) to[out=225,in=135] (4,2)
(4,2) to[out=-45,in=190] (4,1)
(4,1) to[out=-10,in=-10] (3,0)
(3,0) to[out=190,in=290] (0,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: For (1) use `\draw[clip] (0,0) grid (4,4);`

Comment: @Sigur maybe I'm missing something, but simply adding `[clip]` to my code for the grid makes the curve vanish.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your code but something is wrong with the `markings.decorations`. Please, edit your post and add the minimal code so we can copy and paste it.

Comment: @Sigur see if `decorations.markings` works. I'm afraid I swapped the two parts of the library name :). If it doesn't, I'll post the complete minimal code.

Comment: OK, it works now. But now I understand your problem. No solution for a while.

Comment: @MickG instead of correcting mistakes in the comments, why not edit the post so people can see the correct code at the outset? Better yet, why not just write a minimal example that can be copied and pasted by us?

Comment: @PaulGessler done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
\tikzset{invmidarrow/.style={postaction=decorate,decoration={markings,mark={between positions 0 and 1 step #1
with {\arrow{latex reversed}}}}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\draw [clip]
(0,0) to[out=110,in=250] 
(0,2) to[out=70,in=190]
(1,4) to[out=10,in=170] 
(3,4) to[out=-10,in=180]
(4,4) to[out=0.in=45]
(4,3) to[out=225,in=135]
(4,2) to[out=-45,in=190]
(4,1) to[out=-10,in=-10]
(3,0) to[out=190,in=290] (0,0);
\draw (-1,-1) grid (5,5);
\end{scope}
\draw [thick,invmidarrow=10mm]
(0,0) to[out=110,in=250] 
(0,2) to[out=70,in=190]
(1,4) to[out=10,in=170] 
(3,4) to[out=-10,in=180]
(4,4) to[out=0.in=45]
(4,3) to[out=225,in=135]
(4,2) to[out=-45,in=190]
(4,1) to[out=-10,in=-10]
(3,0) to[out=190,in=290] (0,0);
\draw[red,invmidarrow=5mm] (1,1) rectangle (3,3);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

### Edit

Putting

```
\draw[red,invmidarrow=10mm] (1.5,1) -- (1,1) -- (1,3) -- (3,3) -- (3,1) -- cycle;
```

instead of

```
\draw[red,invmidarrow=5mm] (1,1) rectangle (3,3);
```

we get

[image]

and we avoid *markings* on the vertices.

Comment: Why did you use a `scope`? It isn't strictly necessary after all, and it duplicates the code for the curve. Anyway that's exactly what I want, provided I choose which rectangles to put arrows on.

Comment: And the markings on the vertexes look bad, how do I only put those on the edges?

Comment: @MickG `scope` is strictly for use `clip` option for the *grid* and to avoid trim the arrows on the border

Comment: I see now: the arrow tips get trimmed without the scope, since `[clip]` will clip _anything_ that crosses the border of the curve, including marks _on_ the curve. But how do I get the arrows on the angle vertexes to vanish? @skpblack

Comment: @MickG View edit